# Error cannot fetch data from node js server to react server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

Heys guys i tried fetching data from nodejs server to react server in my  Project even though my actions and reducers are working fine but i am getting empty string in my data:"" instead of user's googleID

Here is my code below

Actions.js

```
import axios from "axios";
export const fetchuser = () => {
    return async(dispatch)=>{
       const res=await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/currentuser")
            dispatch({
                type:'fetchuser',
                payload:res
        })
    }
};
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import Header from "./Header";
import * as actions from '../actions'
   class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchuser()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(null,actions)(App)
```

authreducer.js

```
export default function(state={},action){
    console.log(action)
    switch(action.type){
        default:return state
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reducers from './reducers'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'

const store = createStore(reducers,{}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

reducer/index

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import authreducer from './authreducer'
export default combineReducers({
    auth:authreducer
})
```

and i am using npm cors() package to make request from localhost:3000 (React server) to localost:5000/api/currentuser (nodejs server)

So when i directly visit http://localhost:5000/api/currentuser i see the data `{"_id":"5d75807cbd0d3f3ce487a704","googleid":"109463598810933991924","__v":0}`

but then from my react side when in componentdidmount i called this url and prints it on console in authreducer.js
it gives me empty data

```
{type: "fetchuser", payload: {…}}
payload:
config: {url: "http://localhost:5000/api/currentuser", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data: ""
headers: {content-length: "0"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
type: "fetchuser"
__proto__: Object
```

Where is my data lost ?

Comment: `dispatch`? where is it from?

Comment: Can you update the answer and add how you're setting up your store and adding your reducers to your store? Also, are you using redux-thunk?

Comment: I mean where did you import `dispatch` from?

Comment: @ElderPattenFerreira updated and yes m using redux-thunk

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai do you still not understand what I said?

Comment: @zixuan actually yes m too much confused now with redux stuff and i think i havent importer it from anywhere

Comment: Ok, where did `dispatch` come from?

Comment: @zixuan well i am using redux-thunk so we get dispatch function in that i gues ?

Comment: Very good, that is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199151/discussion-between-ratnabh-kumar-rai-and-zixuan).

Comment: I tried reproducing your problem here by using a dummy API I found on Google and the redux is working fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-keller-49xw4?fontsize=14 Can you maybe replace "http://localhost:5000/api/currentuser" for "https://reqres.in/api/users/2" and see if you get a response back?

Comment: @ElderPattenFerreira yepp i am getting response back

Comment: @ElderPattenFerreira you can talk in the chat.